# How to connect my angular app to a google photo album with googlePhotosApi?

Tags: angular, api, google-api, google-photos

I would like to connect my angular app to a google photos album I own.

I activate the API on my google console, I have the key and ID clients OAuth 2.0 : 
[googleconsole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Kpzn.jpg)

I get the oauth2 token of my google account : the account that owns the google photos album.

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() token = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor(private oauthService: OAuthService) {
    this.oauthService.configure(googleAuthConfig);
    this.oauthService.tokenValidationHandler = new JwksValidationHandler();
    this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndTryLogin();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.token.emit(this.oauthService.getAccessToken());
  }

  connectOAuth2 () {
    this.oauthService.initImplicitFlow();
  }

}
```

But I don't understand what I have to do to access through my app to the API and through the API to my album.
Here is a code, i don't know how to pass in the request the credentials. i guess i have to give in the request the id to use the API and the token to access the google account that ownsthe google photo album. Am i right?

```
export class ApiPhotoComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() token;
    public config = {'apiKey' : 'myKey',
                     'oAuthClientID' : 'myClientID',
                     'oAuthclientSecret' : 'myClientSecret',
                     'oAuthCallbackUrl' : 'http://localhost:4200',
                     'port' :  8080,
                     'scopes' :  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly', 'profile'],
                     'photosToLoad' : 150,
                     'searchPageSize' : 100,
                     'albumPageSize' : 50,
                     'apiEndpoint' : 'https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/albums',
                     'token' : 'Bearer ' + this.token};



    constructor(public apiService: ApiService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
    getGooglePhotos() {
        this.apiService.getGooglePhotos( this.config.apiEndpoint, this.config)
            .subscribe(obs => { console.log (obs); }
                , err => { console.log('erreur getContenus section : - section.component.ts -'); });
    }
}
```

the function getGooglePhotos is defining the header like this :

```
getGooglePhotos (url, config) {
      const tokenOption = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
              'X-API-KEY' : config.apiKey,
              'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : 'http://localhost/4200',
              'Content-Type':  'application/json',
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + config.token
          })
      };

      return this.getData( url, tokenOption);
  }
```

Comment: I think this question needs a little more context. do you have a piece of code you are working on? is it client side or server side specifically?

Comment: Actually it's a client side app. For the code, i don't know what to show. I'll try to clean it to show something readable...